# Changing contrast of GeoTIFF using Python

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, sar

I have a GeoTIFF image that I can split into the 4 layers. Now I wish to increase the contrast of the layers and stitch them back together. However when I use numpy to do this, I am unable to increase the contrast of the images.

Current code:

```
def contrast(sLayers):
    optimg=copy.copy(sLayers[:]) 
    for i in range(len(sLayers)):
        copySAR = copy.copy(sLayers[:][i])
        sarArrayI = np.array(copySAR)
#         optimg[i] = cv2.equalizeHist(sarArrayI.astype(uint8))
        clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
        cl1 = clahe.apply(sarArrayI.astype(uint8))
        optimg[i] = cl1
    return(optimg)
```

I used GDAL to open the images and then I use numpy.readAsArray on it which gives sLayers.
Both Clahe and equalize hist fails. How can I change the contrast on the individual layers before merging them for post process?

Comment: Update: fixed the issue (code snippet changed) to be able to change contrast, but the contrast slider in qGIS is very different from the contrast change acheived from the code.

Comment: the contrast in QGIS is defined internally and clips parts of the data to enhance contrasts (either "percent clip" or "standard deviation"). Unless you select "min/max" in the symbology, QGIS will not use the ultimate value range to apply a color scale to the image.